# Recursive method for reversing singly linked list?

Tags: c, recursion, singly-linked-list, generic-programming

I've seen this recursive program (in C language) in

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-function-to-reverse-the-nodes-of-a-linked-list/

for reversing Singly linked list.

```
void recursiveReverse(struct node** head_ref){

struct node* first;
struct node* rest;

/* empty list */
if (*head_ref == NULL)
   return;   

/* suppose first = {1, 2, 3}, rest = {2, 3} */
first = *head_ref;  
rest  = first->next;

/* List has only one node */
if (rest == NULL)
   return;   

/* reverse the rest list and put the first element at the end */
recursiveReverse(&rest);
first->next->next  = first;  

/* tricky step -- see the diagram */
first->next  = NULL;          

/* fix the head pointer */
*head_ref = rest;}
```

In this step in the program,

```
/* reverse the rest list and put the first element at the end */
    recursiveReverse(&rest);
    first->next->next  = first;
```

Can I write " rest->next = first; " instead of " first->next->next = first; " ?

Or is there any significance of writing " first->next->next = first; " ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37725393/reverse-linked-list-recursively

Answer (score 0):

Well, what happened when you tried that change?  Of *course* you can write it… but the semantics may change.

Assigning `first->next` to `rest`does not force them to be always identical.  Your immediately preceding statement passes a *pointer* to `rest` into `recursiveReverse`.  In short, you *expect* `rest` to change.

`rest` should now point to the head of the remainder of the *reversed* list.  This is not `first->next` any more; that should now be the *end* of the reversed list, where `rest` is the head of that list.

Does that explain things well enough?  If not, please put in a few print statements to illustrate what your program does in each case.

Comment: C does not have pass by reference.  A *pointer* to `rest` is passed by value, which is not the same thing.  It does afford the same possibility that the value of `rest` is modified in the caller, however.

Comment: Regarding: “What makes you think […]” Possibly the fact that it works this way in many other areas: Functional programming and math, for example. Having functions with side effects is /not/ intuitive. Please rewrite your answer in a less condescending way.